# Subset data based on pentad dates with leap year

Tags: r, subset, stringr, posixlt

I'm trying to subset the following data by pentad dates. Pentad means non overlapping 5 day average. For leap years, Pentad 12 includes February 29 (6 days average instead of 5):

[Link to Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9faET7Bc2o8NnUybEVUVWp3cTA/view?usp=sharing)

[Link to pentad dates](http://www.hysk.sakura.ne.jp/meteorol/misc/pentad.pdf)

Here's my code:

```
library(stringr)
dat      <- read.csv("tc_filt_1981-2007.csv",header = T,sep = ",")

dat$Date = paste(dat$Year, str_pad(dat$Month,2,'left','0'),    str_pad(dat$Day,2,'left','0'), sep='-')
dat$yday = as.POSIXlt(dat$Date)$yday + 1
dat$pentad = ceiling(dat$yday/5)
df<-split(dat, dat$pentad)
```

Problem:

The **dat$y** line only works for 365 days. In a given year, there should be only 73 pentads. My code above produce 74 pentads when I check the **dat$pentad**. The df contains the data frames for each pentad.

I did the following for checking:

```
test<-dat[which(dat$pentad == 74),]
```

Output:

```
SN     CY Year Month Day  Hour  Lat Lon   Cat   Date yday pentad
200034 34 2000    12  31    0 12.7 128.2  TS 2000-12-31  366     74
200034 34 2000    12  31    6 13.3 128.8  TS 2000-12-31  366     74
200034 34 2000    12  31   12 13.9 129.7  TS 2000-12-31  366     74
200034 34 2000    12  31   18 14.4 130.6  TS 2000-12-31  366     74
```

Question:

1. How do I account for the leap year in my code?

Can anyone suggest how can I do this?

Many thanks,

Comment: What does the definition of _pentad_ say about leap years? Will the February 29 be dropped? Or will Pentad 12 which covers Feb 29 to Mar 01 consist of 6 days instead of 5?

Comment: @UweBlock. You are correct. For leap years, Pentad 12 has 6 days instead of a regular 5 days. Pentad means non overlapping average.

Comment: Now, that the definition of pentads in a leap year has been clarified, you may try to get a list of pentad start dates for one year, create a second list which covers the full time span of your data, and use `cut()` on your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor adjustment:

```
library(lubridate)
dat$pentad = ceiling( (dat$yday - leap_year(dat$Year)*(dat$yday > 59)) / 5 )
```

Comment: Please, note that the code will fail for year 1900 which is a common year. I suggest to use `lubridate::leap_year()`.

Comment: @UweBlock. Thanks for your suggestion. I will try that.